# Does the Logic X Legacy and Compatibility content overwrite the new content?

Tags: logic-pro

I'm trying to help a friend install and configure Logic Pro X from GarageBand which he was previously using and I am confused by the "Legacy and Compatibility" content which I can install. I understand that this content is lower-CPU usage versions and content from the old GarageBand/Logic 8 and 9, is that correct?

What specifically is confusing me is that when I check the box to install the "Legacy and Compatibility" package, the checkboxes for new packages above become checked and the lines are disabled indicating I cannot uncheck them. Does this nean that I will be *overwriting* the *new* versions of these instruments with the *legacy* versions? That's not what I want.

Is it possible to have *both* the new Logic Pro X content *and* the "Legacy and Compatibility" package installed or are they mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Logic X Legacy and Compatibility content overwrite the new content?

**No.**

Legacy and Compatibility content is Jam Pack / Garageband / Logic Studio 2 / LP9 content. It is included so that projects created in those programs will seamlessly open in LPX.

Why some other packages become selected when L&C is checked is beyond me, but in my installation of new and L&C content, new content was not overwritten by legacy versions. New content is available in upper hierarchies of the library for instance, while legacy content lives in their own folders. My guess is there are shared bits between new and GB compatibility content.

In my installation of LPX (I also have LP9 + Jam Packs + GB), both L&C and new LPX content live happily together and are not mutually exclusive.

I have the space so I installed it all. I've never had any incompatibility issues or missing patches/samples/presets.

Comment: Yeah, I always install L&C not just for legacy project support but because there's some genuinely good stuff that just isn't in LPX. And even in L&C they're missing a lot of great stuff from LP8, which is a shame. I wonder if their redistribution rights expired or something.